# Restrict SQL subquery in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I thought the subquery within the select statement will be restricted by the FROM and/or JOIN statements.
Therefore, my query always returns an error because there is more than one row in the subquery.

```
SELECT
      dbo.Countries.Name,
      dbo.Countries.ISO2,
      (SELECT dbo.CountryFields.Field 
       FROM dbo.CountryFields 
       WHERE dbo.CountryFields.Field = 'Population') AS Population
FROM
      dbo.CountryFields
      INNER JOIN
      dbo.Countries ON (dbo.CountryFields.Countries_Id = dbo.Countries.Countries_Id)
```

How can I restrict the number of rows in my subquery?

Do I need there also an inner join Statement inside the subquery? I hoped the subquery will inherit from normal SELECT so I don't need manual restrictions.

The column "Field" contains more than "Population" and I would like to show more rows in the SELECT statement with subselects but now ... I can't even get one column to work. :-(

Comment: What is the structure of these two tables, and a sample of rows from `dbo.CountryFields`? You can correct the subquery with a relating condition to the current row, but this is probably better done with a join.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT
      a.Name,
      a.ISO2,
      (SELECT TOP 1 b.Field FROM dbo.CountryFields b WHERE b.Countries_Id = a.Countries_Id AND b.Field = 'Population') AS Population,
      (SELECT TOP 1 b.Field FROM dbo.CountryFields b WHERE b.Countries_Id = a.Countries_Id AND b.Field = 'Capital') AS Capital,
      (SELECT TOP 1 b.Field FROM dbo.CountryFields b WHERE b.Countries_Id = a.Countries_Id AND b.Field = 'Area') AS Area
FROM
      dbo.Countries a
```

Of course there are ways to optimize the above query, but it's always a tradeoff between readability and speed.

Good luck!

Comment: `OUTER APPLY` may be more performant in this situation, but both are slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like this is the proper query:

```
  SELECT
    C.Name,
    C.ISO2,
    ISNULL(CF_POP.Value,0) AS [Population], 
    ISNULL(CF_F2.Value,0) AS [Field2], 
    ISNULL(CF_F3.Value,0) AS [Field3] 
  FROM
    dbo.Countries AS C 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CountryFields AS CF_POP ON (C.Countries_Id = CF_POP.Countries_Id) AND (CF_POP.Field = 'Population') 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CountryFields AS CF_F2 ON (C.Countries_Id = CF_F2.Countries_Id) AND (CF_F2.Field = 'Field2') 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CountryFields AS CF_F3 ON (C.Countries_Id = CF_F3.Countries_Id) AND (CF_F3.Field = 'Field3')
```

In this example you connect each row from `CountryFields` as a column. I use LEFT JOIN, because I don't know how complete is your data (if you want to see blanks you have to remove ISNULL). I also put column `Value`, because I suppose that there must be second column which corresponds to `CountryFields.Field`. This also can be done with CROSS APPLY, but in that case syntax will be different.